# Удаление Inline клавиатуры со всех предыдущих сообщений Aiogram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram-3.x

Уважаемые пользователи! Есть следующий код:

```
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, F, types
from aiogram.fsm.storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram.filters.command import Command
from aiogram.types import Message
# aiogram 3.1.1.


async def main():
    logging.basicConfig(
        level=logging.INFO,
        format="%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(name)s - %(message)s",
    )

    dp = Dispatcher(storage=MemoryStorage())
    bot = Bot(token='6313233315:AAFnRJlwb3F6VPHAwOb25xNg4xf6rNTFL4o')
    # токен существующего бота @test_bot_forexamblebot, созданного для теста

    builder = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    builder.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton(
        text='Помощь',
        callback_data='help')
    )

    @dp.message(Command('start'))
    async def cmd_help(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Нажми на кнопку Помощь', reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))

    @dp.callback_query(F.data == 'help')
    async def cmd_help(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
        await callback.message.edit_text('Реакция на кнопку Помощь',
                                         reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))

    @dp.message(Command('reset'))
    async def cmd_help(message: Message):
        await message.answer('Клавиатура удалена', reply_markup=builder.as_markup(resize_keyboard=True))
        await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(message.from_user.id, message.message_id - 1, reply_markup=None)

    await dp.start_polling(bot)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Проблема следующая: если пользователь успеет ввести быстро 2 команды /reset до того, как сработает хэндлер, то предыдущая инлайн-клавиатура не удалится, а терминал выдаст ошибку, что сообщение не может быть изменено.

Вопрос: Как реализовать удаление всех предыдущих инлайн-клавиатур со всех сообщений отправленных ботом. bot.edit_message_reply_markup() требует ввода айди чата, айди сообщения и новой клавиатуры.

Answer (score 0):

Моя реализация.

Ошибка, возникающая при попытке отредактировать сообщение, полученное от пользователя относится к категории Bad Request. Данная ошибка по своей сути не является критической и соответственно ее можно игнорировать. Для удаления предыдущих inline клавиатур я использовал обработку исключений, то есть когда программа сталкивается с ошибкой Bad Request программа игнорирует ее и продолжает работу. Реализация следующая:

```
async def remove_inline(message_id, chat_id):
    i = message_id - 2
    while i <= message_id:
        try:
            await bot.edit_message_reply_markup(chat_id, i, reply_markup=None)
            print('edited')
        except aiogram.exceptions.TelegramBadRequest:
            print('not_edited')
        i += 1
# Цикл while "пробегается" по последним двум сообщениям и проверяет есть ли ошибка при попытке отредактировать сообщение. 
# Если ошибка есть, программа игнорирует ее и продолжает работу.
```

Думаю, что предложенная мною реализация довольно "корявая", однако исходя из изученных мною материалов, игнорирование Bad Request используется часто.

Буду очень признателен, если кто-нибудь предложит более чистую реализацию данной фичи.

Идея взята отсюда: https://mastergroosha.github.io/aiogram-3-guide/buttons/#inline-buttons